# (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') [SQL: u'SELECT 1']

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql

The question is 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'. Some say it was just query the too large table, but except this situation.

This error just do the SQL like "select 1" and then we discovers the error:

> (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') [SQL: u'SELECT 1'].

I found the pymysql code and the error log.

The code that raised the exception is
in file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py.

```
def _read_bytes(self, num_bytes):
    self._sock.settimeout(self._read_timeout)
    while True:
        try:
            data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)
            break
        except (IOError, OSError) as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                continue
            self._force_close()
            raise err.OperationalError(
                CR.CR_SERVER_LOST,
                "Lost connection to MySQL server during query (%s)" % (e,))
    if len(data) < num_bytes:     #wops  here
        self._force_close()
        raise err.OperationalError(
            CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
    return data
```

The error log is as below:

```
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/engines.py", line 80, in _connect_ping_listener
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     connection.scalar(select([1]))
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 877, in scalar
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     return self.execute(object, *multiparams, **params).scalar()
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     compiled_sql, distilled_params
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     context)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1398, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     util.raise_from_cause(newraise, exc_info)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     context)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     result = self._query(query)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     conn.query(q)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     result.read()
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 987, in _read_packet
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event     packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
2018-07-06 04:43:19.171 4674 ERROR aodh.evaluator.event   File "/usr
```